# Drag and Drop between Main Page and Pop up

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I am trying to drag and drop an image and text from the main window to a popup window in the same Application.
Here is my code which works when I drop to a  in the same page. But for a popup the dataTransfer object seems to return null.var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text"); is null. What should I be doing differently?

```
<script>
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev){
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);

}

function dragLink(ev){
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
}


function drop(ev){
     ev.preventDefault();
   var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
       ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true));

    return false;
}

</script>
```